# Resample DataFrame per night

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which marks events. 
I need to count the number of these events per night, e.g. evening after 19:00 till morning before 08:00.

I was thinking about using `count()`, but my difficulties are with the switch of date during the night.

I do NOT want `df.resample("d").count()` as this will count all events per calender day, i.e. 00::00 till 24:00. I want all events from 19:00 till 08:00 on the next day.

Here an example code that will generate between 80 and 120 events per night at random times:

```
np.random.seed(843)
rand_times = []
for i in range(5):
    rand_times.extend([datetime.datetime(2015,8,i+12,20,0,0) + pd.Timedelta(k, unit="m") for k in np.random.randint(600, size=np.random.randint(low=80, high=120))])
rand_times.sort()
df = pd.DataFrame(["1234"]*len(rand_times), index=rand_times, columns=["participant_ID"])

df.head()
    participant_ID
2015-08-12 20:02:00     1234
2015-08-12 20:12:00     1234
2015-08-12 20:15:00     1234
2015-08-12 20:19:00     1234
2015-08-12 20:21:00     1234
```

What I have done so far is manually access every night, by looping through them:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(df.loc[(df.index >= datetime.datetime(2015,8,12+i,20,0,0)) & (df.index <= datetime.datetime(2015,8,12+i+1,8))].count())

participant_ID    115
dtype: int64
participant_ID    90
dtype: int64
participant_ID    110
dtype: int64
participant_ID    114
dtype: int64
participant_ID    87
dtype: int64
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? I will need to further process this information, count events per hour per night etc.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for me, using multiindexing. Based on the sample code given above.

```
df_new = []
for i in range(5):
    # iterates through every night
    snipped = df.index[(df.index >= datetime.datetime(2015,8,12+i,20,0,0)) & (df.index <= datetime.datetime(2015,8,12+i+1,8))]
    for row in snipped:
        df_new.append((snipped[0].date(), row))

# create MultiIndex object
myindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df_new, names=["day", "time"])
# create new DataFrame using this multi index
DF = pd.DataFrame(list(df["participant_ID"]), index=myindex, columns=["participant_id"])

# access by night ( first level of multi index)
DF.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0)).count()

day     
2015-08-12  115
2015-08-13  90
2015-08-14  110
2015-08-15  114
2015-08-16  87
```

I am new to Multi-Indexing and would be glad for improvements on this suggestion.

Comment: If I don't receive a better answer within the next 7 days, I will accept my own answer.